# Bindings in XCode 4 for iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, xcode4

I can't find the bindings pane in XCode 4 interface builder. Is it removed? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoa bindings exist only for Mac OS development, not for iOS development.